# A line can be seen inside the circle when using \draw[o-]

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I put a circle using `\draw[o-]` on top of a line, then the line can be seen inside the circle.  It would be nicer if the circle was empty. Here is an example.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) coordinate[label = {right:$y$}] (ymax);
    \draw   (0.25,-0.25) node{{$O$}};
    \draw[o-,thick] (-0.1,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[very thick] (0.1,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw   (-0.25,1) node{{$1$}};
    \draw[o-,thick] (0.1,-1) -- (-2,-1);
    \draw[very thick] (-0.1,-1) -- (-2,-1);
    \draw   (0.4,-1) node{{$-1$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please, make a complete example; I get `Unknown arrow tip kind 'o'`

Comment: I am using the default arrows. It works on my computer.

Comment: You surely have some `\usetikzlibrary` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `o-` arrow tip, I'd like to suggest you another approach using a circular `\node` filled in white and having the desired size; of course, using a style such as `solid` in my example below. You first do all the drawing and then place the circular nodes at the desired locations (a loop simplifies this):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  solid/.style={thick,draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[->] 
  (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [below] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] 
  (0,-2) -- (0,2) coordinate[label = {right:$y$}] (ymax); 
\draw (0.25,-0.25) node{{$O$}}; 
\draw[very thick] 
  (0,1) node[left] {$1$} -- (2,1)
  (0,-1) node[right] {$-1$} -- (-2,-1); 
\foreach \Coord in {(0,1),(0,-1)}
  \node[solid] at \Coord {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good suggestion! I ended up using "\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black]" on top of the other lines. Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Works with all kinds of arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{cours-nk}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) coordinate[label = {right:$y$}] (ymax);
    \draw   (0.25,-0.25) node{{$O$}};
    \draw[{Circle[fill=white]}-,thick] (-0.1,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[very thick] (0.1,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw   (-0.25,1) node{{$1$}};
    \draw[{Circle[fill=white]}-,thick] (0.1,-1) -- (-2,-1);
    \draw[very thick] (-0.1,-1) -- (-2,-1);
    \draw   (0.4,-1) node{{$-1$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A possible addition: `\draw[{Circle[fill=white,line width=0.6pt]}-,very thick] (-0.1,1) -- (2,1);`, and dropping the  `\draw[very thick]` right afterwards. Then you need just one `\draw`, and you don't get the small step in line width (see close to the circle).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. `thick` is not recognized in the arrow head options, but the full path `/tikz/thick` is: `Circle[fill=white, /tikz/thick]`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I tried your improvement, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Tarass It works with the current TikZ version 3.0.0 (I haven't tested it with oder versions).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have this version, I use Texlive 2015. With `\draw[{Circle[fill=white,/tikz/thick,red]}-,thick] (0.1,-1) -- (-2,-1);` I clearly see a small artefact. Maybe I'm wrong in the command and misunderstood what you have wrote ?